# Is it possible to get directions in the past?

Tags: google-maps

I am new to the Google Directions API, and I'm trying to get directions in the past (i.e. not today or any date/time in the future).

I have read about the `arrival_time` and `departure_time` parameters in the [Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro), and it says that you cannot choose a past date/time.

However, through the web interface, I can choose a prior date and time, and it appears to provide a different distance/time estimate than letting the website default to the current date/time.

This leads me to believe it is possible, but I have cannot figure out how to do it, either through the API or through a non-API structured URL.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to set `departure_time` in the past. [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) states:

> The departure_time must be set to the current time or some time in the
>   future. **It cannot be in the past**.

Try the following Directions request (which has `departure_time` set to `10 July`, i.e. 9 days ago as of today).

https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/?origin=California%2C%20USA&destination=Las%20Vegas%2C%20NV%2C%20USA&mode=driving&departure_time=1562766180

You'll see this error:

> Directions request failed due to INVALID_REQUEST - departure_time is
>   in the past. Traffic information is only available for future and
>   current times.

Hope this answers your question.