# Gmapsdistance function not accepting departure times

Tags: r, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I am attempting to give a series of routes to gmapsdistance function. This has previously worked fine with other routes but is not accepting the departure_time arguments with this combination of lat and long.

I have attempted simply entering in a future time in character format ("20:00:00") but get the same error.

```
route_1 <- c(c(57.14748,-2.0954), c(51.12788,-4.25714))
route_2 <- c(c(55.81875,-4.02555), c(51.4721,-0.45273))
route_3 <- c(c(54.96566,-5.0152), c(55.86568,-4.25714))
route_4 <- c(c(51.12788,-4.25714), c(51.38867,0.193838))
route_5 <- c(c(55.86568,-4.25714), c(51.12788,-4.25714))
route_6 <- c(c(51.4721,-0.45273), c(51.12788,-4.25714))

result <- gmapsdistance(origin = route_6[[1]], route_6[[2]],
                        destination = route_6[[3]], route_6[[4]],
                        traffic_model = "pessimistic",
                        mode = "driving", 
                        dep_date = as.character(Sys.Date()), 
                        dep_time = as.character(Sys.time() + 60*10),
                        key=key,
                        combinations = "all",
                        avoid = "")``
```

Error received is strangely:

```
The departure time has to be some time in the future!
```

Comment: You cannot set departure_time in the past. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57114880/11742502

Comment: Sorry it's not related to the above, please see my answer below and let us know if it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to setting `departure_time` in the past like the error indicates. It actually looks like it's stemming from an invalid format for `origin` & `destination` and for `dep_time`.

According to the library's [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gmapsdistance/versions/3.4), the coordinates should be formatted as follows:

```
"38.1621328+24.0029257"
```

And departure time should only contain a time, not a date+time. E.g.:

```
"20:40:00"
```

Please try running the full code below (with your API key):

```
library("gmapsdistance")

set.api.key("AIza...")

route_6 <- c(c("51.4721+-0.45273"), c("51.12788+-4.25714"))

results = gmapsdistance(origin = route_6[[1]],
                        destination = route_6[[2]],
                        traffic_model = "pessimistic",
                        mode = "driving", 
                        dep_date = as.character(Sys.Date()), 
                        dep_time = as.character(format(Sys.time() + 60*10, "%H:%M:%S")),
                        key=get.api.key(),
                        combinations = "all",
                        avoid = "")
results
```

Which for me as of now it returns:

```
$Time
[1] 16842

$Distance
[1] 337527

$Status
[1] "OK"
```

Hope this helps!